# Can a complex number be unpacked into x and y in python?

Tags: python, complex-numbers, iterable-unpacking

I want to be able to unpack a complex number into its real and imaginary parts like so:

```py
>>> z = 3 + 5j
>>> x, y = z
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable complex object
```

but I get an error. Of course I can do:

```py
>>> x, y = z.real, z.imag
```

but this seems repetitive and not very readable, I can improve this by writing a function like this:

```py
def unpack(z: complex) -> tuple[float, float]:
    return z.real, z.imag
x, y = unpack(z)
```

but I feel like there should be a better way.

Do you know a better way to unpack a complex number into its real and imaginary parts?

Comment: What do you consider a "better way"? Shorter? Builtin?

Comment: I think your `unpack` function is the simplest and most readable way.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ideally, builtin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is subclass `complex` and implement a custom `__iter__` method that returns the unpacked version you seek.

I chose to call it `complez` in this case, since `z` is often a symbol for a complex number.

```
import cmath

class complez(complex):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self.real, self.imag))

z = complez(3, 5)
x, y = z
print(x, y)
# 3.0 5.0
```

You can also do the following, if you don't mind overriding the existing `complex`. Using this approach allows you to continue using the `complex` class throughout your code without needing to make any changes to naming.

```
import builtins
import cmath

class complex(builtins.complex):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self.real, self.imag))

z = complex(3, 5)
x, y = z
print(x, y)
# 3.0 5.0
```

(Technically, you could also drop the use of the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) module).

In either case, the standard unpacking operator would also work, e.g.

```
print(*z)
# 3.0 5.0
```

**NOTE:** This solves your immediate problem, but it does have consequences. When you perform operations on these new numbers, e.g. adding 2 `complez` numbers, you would get a `complex` number result -- which won't have the convenient `__iter__` defined, so you'd have to override other methods to account for this side-effect. For example:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return complez(super().__add__(other))
```

Hence, this approach does result in more overhead in producing a fully general solution. But, this is the tradeoff for having the convenience of natural unpacking.

Comment: This will work for complex numbers created "literally" using the `complez` constructor, but the result of arithmetic on `complez` objects will still be `complex` objects. You might want to override the relevant methods to return `complez` instead.

Comment: Could also just `yield` them.

Comment: True @kaya3, good point, this would have consequences like that, I've make a note of that in the answer.